Why the distribution with rank 2 in $\mathbb{S}^3$ is not involution?
In our differential geometry class, professor mentioned that all distributions with rank 2 in $\mathbb{S}^3$ are not integral i.e. not involution. It seems like to compute the Lie bracket for the sections of any such distribution.
There is a natural inclusion $\mathbb{S}^3\to \mathbb{C}^2$ and there special left-invariant vector field of $\mathbb{S}^3$:
$$X_1=pi,\quad X_2=pj,\quad X_3=pk$$
where $i,j,k$ are quaternions and
$$[X_1,X_2]=2X_3,\quad [X_2,X_3]=2X_1,\quad [X_3,X_1]=2X_2$$
so if the distribution of $\mathbb{S}^3$ with rank 2 generated by $X_i,X_j,i\ne j$, then it's not involution. Noticed that $X_1,X_2,X_3$ are global frame of $\mathbb{S}^3$, it seems that use the fact and the Lie brackets $[X_i,X_j]$, we can prove all distributions of $\mathbb{S}^3$ with rank 2 are not involution. But it not obviously to say a distribution with rank 2 is not involution by using above statement to compute the Lie bracket?

Have you tried computing the Lie bracket of $Y=\sum \alpha_iX_i$ and $Z=\sum \beta_jX_j$? (It's easier to approach this question, by the way, using the integrability criterion phrased in terms of differential forms.)

@TedShifrin I have tried computing the Lie brackets, indeed for any vector fields $X=a^iX_i,\quad Y=b^jX_j$ we have $[X,Y]=a^i(X_ib^j)X_j-b^j(X_ja^i)X_i+a^ib^j[X_i,X_j]$. There are too many terms to observe $[X,Y]\notin span{X,Y}$.

The exist an involutive rank 2 distribution  on $S^3$ : the tangent distribution of the so called Reeb foliation. See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reeb_foliation

@Thomas May be our professor’s assertion is wrong. He leaves a homework to compute Hopf fibration and thinks all distributions of $\mathbb{S}^3$ with rank 2 are not integrable.
